# What are the advantages of coupling/de-coupling HTML generation to event handling?

Tags: html, event-handling

I'm currently deciding between two different approaches for generating HTML with event handlers.  I know both approaches are viable (I've seen both used before), but I'm unclear on their respective advantages, and since I'll be stuck with whichever one I pick I was hoping someone might be able to clarify those advantages for me.

Here's a simplistic example to explain the idea (although my real world cases will of course be more complex).  Let's say we want to have a button that alerts "Hello Bob".  The first approach is to use our view logic to generate the HTML, and then rely on a separate, high-level event handler:

```
$('body').append('<button class="nameAlert" data-name="Bob">Click me</button>')

$('body').on('click .nameAlert', function(e) {
    alert('Hello ' + $(e.target).data('name'));
})
```

The second approach is to build an element object, bind a handler to it, and then append it to the DOM, all at once:

```
var $button = $('<button>Click me</button');
var name = "Bob";
$button.on('click', function(e) {
    alert('Hello ' + name);
});
$('body').append($button);
```

There are some obvious advantages to the latter approach (eg. no writing data attributes, all the logic is one place) but I'm really curious about the non-obvious advantages (eg. the first version will perform better if we wind up with a lot of these buttons on the page).  I'm **especially** interested in maintainability (that should be a programmer's first priority, right?).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are asking about is event delegation.  Event delegation allows you to bind the event handler on a parent DOM element and handle events that occur within it. There are a number of benefits from this pattern, not the greatest of which is less repetitive code:

1. **Efficiency**.  The browser does not have to attach event handlers to multiple dom elements.
2. **Memory Leaks**.  It helps avoid memory leaks caused by dom elements being removed from the DOM that still have a javascript object referring to them.  Since your parent element typically stays in the DOM as its children change, this doesn't happen.
3. **Live binding**.  Event delegation will fire on any descendent node that matches the delegation selector, which means they can be added after the fact and still work.

I'm sure there are other benefits but those are some of the primary reasons for choosing event delegation.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I was looking for a higher-level answer though.  Delegation certainly has benefits, but it also means (for instance) putting your HTML-generation code in a different place from your event delegation code, and maybe that makes the code harder to maintain?  That was more the sort of thing I was hoping to get feedback on.